# Beginner's text for Algebraic Number Theory

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, book-recommendation

What's a good book for learning Algebraic Number Theory with minimum prerequisites?
Assume that the reader has done a basic abstract algebra course.

Comment: Marcus has a good text (http://www.amazon.com/Number-Fields-Universitext-Daniel-Marcus/dp/0387902791) as well as Samuel (http://www.amazon.com/Algebraic-Theory-Numbers-Translated-Mathematics/dp/0486466663)

Comment: @jspecter I was about to recommend the very same! With a few more words your comment would make a good answer.

Comment: It would help if you revealed more about your goals. For example, do you plan to go on to do research in number theory or, is your aim to obtain a solid background for applications such as cryptography?

Comment: Research in Number theory. Actually, I'm interested in the Langlands program.

Answer (score 13):

I'm a big fan of Murty and Esmonde's "Problems in algebraic number theory", which develops the basic theory through a series of problems (with the answers in the back).  Another nice source is Milne's notes on algebraic number theory, available on his website [here](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ant.html).

Comment: Milne's notes have answers at the end as well.

Answer (score 12):

I would recommend Ireland and Rosen's text [Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441930949). The prerequisites for the first 10 or so chapters are minimal (first semester undergraduate algebra course).

Comment: Although very good, this is an elementary number theory textbook with one chapter ( out of 20 ) dedicated to ANT.

Answer (score 12):

I would recommend Stewart and Tall's [Algebraic Number Theory and Fermat's Last Theorem](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568811195) for an introduction with minimal prerequisites. For example you don't need to know any module theory at all and all that is needed is a basic abstract algebra course (assuming it covers some ring and field theory). But again the first chapter gives a quick review of the basic material from abstract algebra that is used later on.

I have used this book when I took an introductory course in Algebraic Number Theory and the experience was really good. The book has many examples and the pace is not too fast.

Most other books I have seen rely more heavily on module theory to make the exposition more general but since probably you don't have that background yet then I guess that this book may very well suit you perfectly.

Comment: Add Stewart's book on Galois Theory to the 'minimal' requirements. The book is full of references to it. Both books are too sketchy to really grasp the topic from it.

Comment: I second ndroock1.  Stewart and Tall's Algebraic Number Theory and Fermat's Last Theorem is supposed to be an introduction to the subject, but it has several logical gaps that beginners may find hard to fill in.  I would choose Alaca and Williams instead.

Comment: Just a note that a [fourth edition](https://www.amazon.com/Algebraic-Number-Theory-Fermats-Theorem-dp-1498738397/dp/1498738397/ref=dp_ob_title_bk) appeared in 2015.

Answer (score 6):

I liked [Algebraic Theory of Numbers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486466663) by Pierre Samuel.

Answer (score 3):

Paulo Ribenboim, A Classical Introduction to Algebraic Numbers, Springer 2001 https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1873959.Classical_Theory_of_Algebraic_Numbers
" The exposition of the classical theory of algebraic numbers is clear and thorough, and there is a large number of exercises as well as worked out numerical examples. A careful study of this book will provide a solid background to the learning of more recent topics. "

Answer (score 3):

There are notes by William A. Stein, in particular if you like to use computer to experiment: https://wstein.org/books/ant/ant.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I like Algebraic Number Theory, Second Edition by  [Richard A. Mollin](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439845980). It is simple and best book to self study.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [Fermat's Last Theorem: A Genetic Introduction to Algebraic Number Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387950028) by Harold M. Edwards.

I quote:

> This introduction to algebraic number theory via the famous problem of "Fermat's Last Theorem" follows its historical development, beginning with the work of Fermat and ending with Kummer's theory of "ideal" factorization. The more elementary topics, such as Euler's proof of the impossibilty of $x^3 +y^3 = z^3$, are treated in an uncomplicated way, and new concepts and techniques are introduced only after having been motivated by specific problems. The book also covers in detail the application of Kummer's theory to quadratic integers and relates this to Gauss' theory of binary quadratic forms, an interesting and important connection that is not explored in any other book.

Answer (score 2):

Paul Pollack, A Conversational Introduction to Algebraic Number Theory: Arithmetic Beyond $\bf Z$

From the American Math Society [website](https://bookstore.ams.org/stml-84):

Gauss famously referred to mathematics as the “queen of the sciences” and to number theory as the “queen of mathematics”. This book is an introduction to algebraic number theory, meaning the study of arithmetic in finite extensions of the rational number field $\bf Q$. Originating in the work of Gauss, the foundations of modern algebraic number theory are due to Dirichlet, Dedekind, Kronecker, Kummer, and others. This book lays out basic results, including the three “fundamental theorems”: unique factorization of ideals, finiteness of the class number, and Dirichlet's unit theorem. While these theorems are by now quite classical, both the text and the exercises allude frequently to more recent developments.

In addition to traversing the main highways, the book reveals some remarkable vistas by exploring scenic side roads. Several topics appear that are not present in the usual introductory texts. One example is the inclusion of an extensive discussion of the theory of elasticity, which provides a precise way of measuring the failure of unique factorization.

The book is based on the author's notes from a course delivered at the University of Georgia; pains have been taken to preserve the conversational style of the original lectures.

Readership:
Undergraduate and graduate students interested in algebraic number theory.

Comment: See also https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/a-conversational-introduction-to-algebraic-number-theory for a review.

Answer (score 1):

*Quadratic Number Theory: An Invitation to Algebraic Methods in the Higher Arithmetic* by J. L. Lehman. I read this as supplementary material to Cox's *Primes of the Form $x^2+ny^2$* and Ireland & Rosen's *A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory*.

Answer (score 1):

Jarvis's *Algebraic Number Theory* is a gentle, undergraduate introduction. It is certainly accessible with basic abstract algebra - groups up to Lagrange's theorem and some familiarity with rings and fields are enough to get started, along with linear algebra and a little elementary number theory.

Answer (score 1):

The book *Introductory Algebraic Number Theory* by Saban Alaca & Kenneth S. Williams is a good choice to start studying algebraic number theory.

Answer (score 0):

I want to recommend the Neukirch book "Algebraic Number Theorey". It is a good book.

Comment: It is a good book, but is it appropriate for beginners? The OP refers to minimum prerequisites, assuming only a basic abstract algebra course.