# Number Fields (by Marcus), part (c) of exercise 9 chapter 3

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, prime-factorization

Let $K$ and $L$ be number fields with $K \subset L$, and let $R = \mathbb{A} \cap K$ and $S = \mathbb{A} \cap L$. Part (c) asks us to characterize the ideals of $S$ such that $I = (I \cap R) S$.

The same question is asked here: [Algebraic number theory, Marcus, Chapter 3, Question 9](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1736479/algebraic-number-theory-marcus-chapter-3-question-9). Although the problem is solved, I cannot understand the solution there.

The first two parts of the question (or the results I known) are

1. Let $I, J$ be ideals in $R$. If $IS \mid JS$ then $I \mid J$.
2. For each ideal $I$ in $R$, we have $I = IS \cap R$.

I am wondering if part (c) is related to these results.

Comment: What is $\mathbb A$ here?

Comment: The ring of all algebraic integers.

Answer (score 2):

I will show that $I$ satisfies the condition if and only if it is of the form $JS$, where $J$ is an ideal in $R$.

Suppose $I = JS$ for some ideal $J$ in $R$. Then by part (b) of the problem, $I\cap R = JS\cap R = J$. This implies, $(I\cap R)S = JS = I$.

Conversely, suppose $(I\cap R)S = I$. It suffices to show that $I\cap R$ is an ideal in R, but this is easy to see.

Comment: Very nice. I was thinking that it will probably make sense just for inert primes.