# A book about Algebraic number theory in order to learn about elliptic curves?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, book-recommendation

I am an undergraduate student and currently I am reading Atiyah-Macdonald book about Commutative Algebra which I find extremely clear and concise.
I would like to read and study "The arithmetic of elliptic curves" By Silverman, which covers an apparently interesting subject about which my university offers no courses.
As stated above, I need to build the necessary background in algebraic number theory.
Silverman's book gives as references Lang's or Shafarevich's books about the subject, which surely cover all needed but seem quite extensive.

Does also Samuel Pierre's book cover everything i need? If not, is there a shorter introduction than the two presented above?

I want to make clear a few things:

1. During my master studies I will surely expand on the subject, that's why I am looking for an introduction as brief as possible.
2. The final goal is to be able to write a thesis about elliptic curves from an algebraic-geometry viewpoint. That's why I am probably going to follow a scheme theory course next year, for which I am preparing with Atiyah's.
3. It is also my understanding that some algebraic number theory would help me in Commutative Algebra, by presenting examples and motivation for the rather general theory.
4. I am self-studying, so probably some books are better than others.

Comment: I think that Silverman's book on elliptic curves is enough for your final goal. If you really need more background, you can specifically look it up then instead of taking a whole course in algebraic number theory or algebraic geometry. However, if you want some book recommendations for algebraic number theory on a beginner level, then see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66086/beginners-text-for-algebraic-number-theory) for example. Search this site for more yourself!

Comment: The first two chapters of Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory contain more than what you need. Books like Marcus's Number Fields or Jarvis's Algebraic Number Theory will be easier reading (the latter as an undergrad textbook), but won't get you as far as $p$-adic fields, which you need for chapter VII. You could supplement these books with Serre's Local Fields. I learnt this stuff through lectures and lecture notes... so hopefully someone else can give better suggestions! But honestly, the pre-reqs for Silverman are really mild. You don't need a full course in number theory!

Comment: You'd probably be alright consulting [Keith Conrad's expository articles on the subject](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/).

Comment: I agree with Mathmo, the prerequisites are very mild. In fact, a good excercise reading this book is to specialise to $K = \mathbb{F}_p, \mathbb{Q}_p$, and $\mathbb{Q}$ as your favourite finite, local, and global field. In which cases a lot of things become much more elementary - for ex you don't need class and unit groups to prove the weak MW theorem

Comment: Since Milne has both lecture notes on Algebraic Number Theory and Elliptic Curves, as well as continuations (e.g. Class Field Theory & Abelian Varieties respectively), I think it is good to mention them here. The notes on Algebraic Number theory cover more or less the same as the first two chapters in Neukirch. If you know commutative algebra at the level of Atiyah/MacDonald, reading Silverman, (language-wise) the harder part will be the geometry rather than the number theory; that is why there is an introduction to classical algebraic geometry in the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samuel's book is very usefull for the basics of algebraic number theory, i.e., Dedekind rings, splitting of primes, class group etc. with which you should surely be comfortable with at some point. Also because Elliptic curves gives you Dedekind rings as they coordinate rings.
Furthermore, the book builds every result needed, giving you some quite useful example in commutative algebra and theorems stated in a narrower generality than in the AM. This may be helpfull for somebody who is self studying.

Then probably for everything else you need you can either pick Serre's Local fields or Neukirch. However if your purpose is only understanding the book by Silverman, then you can avoid the chapters on Class field theory and just read the first couple of both books, which cover the construction and classification of local fields.
Class field theory is a beautiful subject, but is not needed and you may find yourself stuck in a rabbit hole.

**Edit**:
I forgot to mention that another book which covers the same material as Samuel is Marcus's "Number Fields". It has the advantage of having plenty of exercises.